# HP BIOS Update / Recovery fails

Tags: bios, updates, recovery

Questions:

1) Is there any specific issue causing this? I've seen this in some topics but no true solution.

2) If there is no available software solutions, does sending my laptop to a repair center solve it?

NB : I have Windows 8.1, I can boot to it and even play games , do heavy rendering / Coding , i can also access BIOS, but BIOS won't save new settings, and bootable USB drives won't boot.

In case the log is hard to read:

Major Errors:

```
  Verify of Block 1056 Failed

  Failed Reading BIOS Signature File Hewlett-Packard\BIOS\Current\0227D.sig
```

So for now, here is the logfile:

```
01/04/19 11:35:02  EFI HP BIOS Update 3.0.0.0 Started
01/04/19 11:35:07  HP BIOS Image Interface Protocol Version 2.0
01/04/19 11:35:09  BattInit: Protocol 2010.
01/04/19 11:35:09  All Required Protocols Located
01/04/19 11:35:09  System ID: 2281
01/04/19 11:35:10  System ID = 2281
01/04/19 11:35:10  HpBiosUpdate.Mode = 4
01/04/19 11:35:10  Current Directory = HEWLETT-PACKARD\BIOSUpdate\
01/04/19 11:35:10  SMBIOS Init Success
01/04/19 11:35:10  SystemFamily = 2
01/04/19 11:35:10  PlatformLang reported as en-US.
01/04/19 11:35:10  Language Selected is currently (eng).
01/04/19 11:35:10  Starting BIOS Update Process
01/04/19 11:35:10  Setting BIOS Update Token
01/04/19 11:35:10  Getting BIOS Detail Information
01/04/19 11:35:10  BIOS Returned BiosID '0227D'
01/04/19 11:35:10  Loading BIOS Image
01/04/19 11:35:10  File name constructed: Hewlett-Packard\BIOS\Current\0227D.bin
01/04/19 11:35:11  Reading New BIOS Image Hewlett-Packard\BIOS\Current\0227D.bin
01/04/19 11:35:11  Getting BIOS version from file image
01/04/19 11:35:11  Bios Version = F.04
01/04/19 11:35:11  Verifying AC or Battery Power Status
01/04/19 11:35:11  Verifying Binary match
01/04/19 11:35:11  Loading Signature File
01/04/19 11:35:11  Failed Reading BIOS Signature File Hewlett-Packard\BIOS\Current\0227D.sig
01/04/19 11:35:16  Bios Verify Signature Success (Success)
01/04/19 11:35:22  Loading Password File if required
01/04/19 11:35:22  Writing BIOS Image
01/04/19 11:38:18  Verifying Written BIOS Image
01/04/19 11:40:11  Verify of Block 1056 Failed
01/04/19 11:40:13  Verify of Block 1057 Failed
01/04/19 11:40:19  Verify of Block 1058 Failed
01/04/19 11:40:19  Verify of Block 1059 Failed
01/04/19 11:40:19  Verify of Block 1060 Failed
01/04/19 11:40:19  Verify of Block 1061 Failed
01/04/19 11:40:20  Verify of Block 1077 Failed
01/04/19 11:40:25  Skipping Verification Block 1104 Address 0x0000000000450000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:40:29  Next BlockIndex 1105, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000451000
01/04/19 11:41:24  Skipping Verification Block 1771 Address 0x00000000006EB000 Size 0x0000000000011000
01/04/19 11:41:26  Next BlockIndex 1788, BlockAddress = 0x00000000006FC000
01/04/19 11:41:32  Skipping Verification Block 1788 Address 0x00000000006FC000 Size 0x0000000000060000
01/04/19 11:41:32  Next BlockIndex 1884, BlockAddress = 0x000000000075C000
01/04/19 11:41:32  Skipping Verification Block 1884 Address 0x000000000075C000 Size 0x00000000000A4000
01/04/19 11:41:32  Next BlockIndex 2048, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000800000
01/04/19 11:41:32  Failed VerifyImage Call Status (Device Error)
01/04/19 11:41:32  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1056 Address 0x0000000000420000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:41:32  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1057 Address 0x0000000000421000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:41:32  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1058 Address 0x0000000000422000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:41:32  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1059 Address 0x0000000000423000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:41:32  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1060 Address 0x0000000000424000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:41:33  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1061 Address 0x0000000000425000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:41:33  Retry Iteration 2: Block 1077 Address 0x0000000000435000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:43:23  Verify of Block 1056 Failed
01/04/19 11:43:26  Verify of Block 1057 Failed
01/04/19 11:43:31  Verify of Block 1058 Failed
01/04/19 11:43:31  Verify of Block 1059 Failed
01/04/19 11:43:31  Verify of Block 1060 Failed
01/04/19 11:43:32  Verify of Block 1061 Failed
01/04/19 11:43:33  Verify of Block 1077 Failed
01/04/19 11:43:38  Skipping Verification Block 1104 Address 0x0000000000450000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:43:42  Next BlockIndex 1105, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000451000
01/04/19 11:44:36  Skipping Verification Block 1771 Address 0x00000000006EB000 Size 0x0000000000011000
01/04/19 11:44:38  Next BlockIndex 1788, BlockAddress = 0x00000000006FC000
01/04/19 11:44:44  Skipping Verification Block 1788 Address 0x00000000006FC000 Size 0x0000000000060000
01/04/19 11:44:44  Next BlockIndex 1884, BlockAddress = 0x000000000075C000
01/04/19 11:44:44  Skipping Verification Block 1884 Address 0x000000000075C000 Size 0x00000000000A4000
01/04/19 11:44:44  Next BlockIndex 2048, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000800000
01/04/19 11:44:44  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1056 Address 0x0000000000420000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:44:44  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1057 Address 0x0000000000421000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:44:44  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1058 Address 0x0000000000422000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:44:45  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1059 Address 0x0000000000423000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:44:45  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1060 Address 0x0000000000424000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:44:45  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1061 Address 0x0000000000425000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:44:45  Retry Iteration 1: Block 1077 Address 0x0000000000435000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:46:36  Verify of Block 1056 Failed
01/04/19 11:46:38  Verify of Block 1057 Failed
01/04/19 11:46:44  Verify of Block 1058 Failed
01/04/19 11:46:44  Verify of Block 1059 Failed
01/04/19 11:46:44  Verify of Block 1060 Failed
01/04/19 11:46:44  Verify of Block 1061 Failed
01/04/19 11:46:45  Verify of Block 1077 Failed
01/04/19 11:46:50  Skipping Verification Block 1104 Address 0x0000000000450000 Size 0x0000000000001000
01/04/19 11:46:54  Next BlockIndex 1105, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000451000
01/04/19 11:47:49  Skipping Verification Block 1771 Address 0x00000000006EB000 Size 0x0000000000011000
01/04/19 11:47:51  Next BlockIndex 1788, BlockAddress = 0x00000000006FC000
01/04/19 11:47:57  Skipping Verification Block 1788 Address 0x00000000006FC000 Size 0x0000000000060000
01/04/19 11:47:57  Next BlockIndex 1884, BlockAddress = 0x000000000075C000
01/04/19 11:47:57  Skipping Verification Block 1884 Address 0x000000000075C000 Size 0x00000000000A4000
01/04/19 11:47:57  Next BlockIndex 2048, BlockAddress = 0x0000000000800000
01/04/19 11:47:57  Failed RetryBlocks Call Status (Device Error)
01/04/19 11:47:57  Setting Flash Completion Status
01/04/19 11:47:57  BIOS Update Process Complete
```

Comment: How are you determining that the update failed? You state you can get into windows but is your core problem that you can't save bios settings? What prompted you to flash the bios in the first place? What wasn't working before?

Comment: hi , everything was working fine until i needed ubuntu for a college project , which that famouse BIOS bug caused by ubuntu 17.10 happened , and now BIOS won't save setting , and i can't boot from usb , i tried to recover using A USB made on that windows 8.1 and then did the "Win + B + Power button" combination , and recovery failed . 

thank you for your time , is there anything i can do?

Comment: Installing Ubuntu doesn't flash the motherboard though. It loads a boot loader that manages what is booting. What you should do is format the drive completely to ensure no boot loader is on it and then install Windows fresh again

Comment: It is possible the HP BIOS is locked down, some of them have a "Secure Boot" thing that prevents bootable USB drives as well as modifying the BIOS. But, messing with Secure Boot affects the boot "mode" (UEFI boot vs Legacy), so it may make your OS non-bootable, but can always change back to the former setting, just make notes.

Comment: thats exactly what i thought , i thought that any kind of OS , shouldn't do any harm to the BIOS , until i ve been proven wrong the hard way , the thing is this is my main PC , and i am afraid of the worse ( PC with no OS , and a corrupted BIOS )

Comment: studiohack , Secure boot isn't enabled, but now changing anything on bios won't take effect , like for example CPU virtualization is deactivated , and activating it does nothing

Comment: i will be patient and wait for answers for now ,before i go to some technician

Comment: It is still possible that it is merely locked down which would be why you can't save things. From what you have stated so far, I don't think anything is wrong with your BIOS however if you feel that this is not true then you could always flash it to the latest. Do keep in mind that generally flashing a working motherboard isn't best practice as it can sometimes cause more harm than good. As a note, if you want people to be notified you responded, put the @ sign in front of their name

Comment: @EricF thank you for your suggestion, i would like to know if there is a way to unlock it , and by flashing , you mean through usb , or manual flashing through hardware utilities?

Comment: @EricF, do you mean by "locked" , with a password? , for clarification , this bios (UEFI) doesn't have password and i can access the settings and everything is working inside it , only that it doesn't save changes and keep going back to the previous state (i can't even set defaults) , thank you for your time again , im waiting for your reply

Comment: Flashing is updating / reinstalling the firmware that the motherboard uses. The method to do so can be different among manufacturers however most usually require a disk or something external to be ran to load it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : tried it and succeeded to fix my laptop hp pavion 15

[Link to the fix video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpeK-G_l8_s&t=3s)

Edit: Steps in case the link doesn't work: **if you can boot into ubuntu 17.10 you can skip step 1 and 2:**

**Step1** : install Ubuntu 17.10 with Grub on a USB flash disk ( preferably 8GB and up)

**Step2** : remove your laptop's Hard disk drive to avoid any loss of data or any kind of risk

**Step3** : prepare the update as provided from Ubuntu's team in a Second USB flash disk (yes we will work with 2 USBs and this is how i did it)

**Step4** : boot to your Ubuntu 17.10 which is installed in the first USB

**Step5** : after you booted up, insert the second USB and install that update ( either with the insltaller or the terminal)

**Step6** : turn off your laptop , turn it on , once on the GRUB choose the newly installed kernel , click enter and wait for it to install

**Step7** : Your laptop is saved.